# Apache internal dummy connections

Tags: apache-2.2

In my Apache access log I have more than 10 million of such queries:

```
::1 - - [21/Nov/2011:16:15:54 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.2.13 (internal dummy connection)"
```

Is it due to the mod_rewrite redirects or what? Why are they shown in the IPv6 notation? Let me know if you require more info on the server configuration. I use Debian 5.0.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are an internal Apache mechanism used for things like creating new child processes.  They are nothing for you to worry about.

Comment: Thanks. Can I make Apache not to log such queries? I assume it takes some server resources and I/O to log them.

Comment: You can but you probably shouldn't.  You can use them as a gauge for performance tuning your system.  You are better off telling your log analyzer to ignore them, (if the analyzer is even considering them).  Each line is only using about 130 bytes in your log.

Comment: When you see them, it is a sign that apache is killing off a bunch of workers that are above the maximum spare. If you see it a lot, its a sign that you should probably have a higher minimum number of workers.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do it in your httpd.conf file.
You probably have this line:

`CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined`

Change it to this:

`SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" dontlog
CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined env=!dontlog`

Source:  https://www.electrictoolbox.com/apache-stop-logging-internal-dummy-connection/